# Debugging WebAssembly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, emscripten, webassembly, firefox-developer-tools

I'm a relative newbie to WebAssembly, but I've been working with it and Emscripten for about a month now, and have a decent familiarity with the minimal build kits.

When it comes to debugging, I am finding that I cannot find how get the most out of both Chrome and Firefox environments.

In Firefox 68.0.1 my Source Map files load and I can map them correctly to my C/C++ source files.

I cannot, however, see the local stack. I can see all the local variables, but as I step through my wasm code, as FF displays it, it's pushing things to a stack I can't see, and keeping track of that manually is a pain.

Chrome 76, by contrast, gives me the stack, will let me add the Source Map to see my C/C++ references, but I cannot get it to give me any kind of wasm code to step through, either my own wast file, or its own disassembled version.

All wasm I load, either from node http-server or from emscripten emrun, shows me my source code in the "Sources" tab of DevTools, but there is a second node under localhost that is labeled "top/(no domain)." I've tried loading a simple module with no success.

[image: simple hello world demo]

I would like to either figure out how to view the local stack in FireFox or get Chrome to show me the wasm disassembly (preferably both). Chrome seems to do so for WebAssembly Studio and I cannot find out why

[image]

Comment: As uncouth as it may be, I usually printf debug wasm...